# SQL statement: How to get a special output for NULL value in aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
| NULL |
|    5 |
|    6 |
+------+
```

This is table test.

```
select max(num) from test;   ---> 6
```

How to write a SQL statement that
if NULL values exists  --> output should be "OK"

if NULL values does not exist in this column --> output should be 6

I try many times but no luck. Any help? 
It would be nice if the solution is ANSI SQL

Comment: Based on your comment to an answer, I've added a `mysql` tag. It always helps to tell people which RDBMS you're using when asking SQL questions.

Comment: it's that possible to write for an ANSI SQL, i wanna try a generic one

Comment: It's fine to *ask* for standard answers, but they may not always be the best or even possible sometimes - and if you don't give the database, people will guess at one - if you're lucky, they'll tell you in their answers which one they've guessed at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfcbd/2

This:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (`num` int);

INSERT INTO tbl
    (`num`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (NULL),
    (5),
    (6);

select if(bit_or(num is null), 'OK', max(num)) as max from tbl;
```

Outputs:

```
OK
```

This:

```
CREATE TABLE tblx
    (`num` int);

INSERT INTO tblx
    (`num`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),    
    (5),
    (6);

select if(bit_or(num is null), 'OK', max(num)) as max from tblx;
```

Outputs:

```
6
```

Comment: can you explain the use of bit_or to me i don't quite understand why it works.

Comment: you can read that bit_or as ANY, anything that has a match at least one, turns things to true. it's analogous to bool_or of Postgresql

Comment: On the opposite requirement, i.e. to find if everything is null, you can use bit_and (bool_and in Postgresql). There's an alias for bool_and in Postgresql, it's called EVERY. I think bool_or (and bit_or for that matter) was not named ANY as there's already an SQL construct that uses the ANY keyword

Comment: An example of bool_and http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/why-i-like-postgresql-it-has-first.html

Comment: for this one, is it an ansi SQL?

Comment: Nope, this answer is not very ANSI SQL, it has too many MySQLism. For one, there's an implicit conversion from integer to string; second we uses integer result as boolean, like in C; third, not all database has boolean,MySQL integer/boolean duality makes checking more succint. e.g. this works on MySQL: `SUM(num is NULL) as null_count`, unlike other database that doesn't support boolean, they have to do this: `SUM(case when num is null then 1 else 0 end)`. Though I don't know if ANSI SQL mandated that a database must support proper boolean for a database to identified an ANSI SQL-conforming one

Comment: The first query here is ANSI SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027560/sql-statement-how-to-get-a-special-output-for-null-value-in-aggregate-function/11028150#11028150

Comment: I prefer this answer, it is short enough!

Answer (score 2):

ANSI SQL below http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/679b2/1

Most database don't have first-class boolean type, hence the query is longer. And many database, don't implicitly convert an integer to varchar

```
select

  case when count(case when num is null then 1 end) > 0 then 
     'OK' 
  else
     cast(max(num) as varchar(16))
  end

from tbl
```

If every database has first-class boolean, the above could be shortened to:

```
select

  case when sum(cast( (num is null) as int )) > 0 then 
    'OK' 
  else
    cast(max(num) as varchar(16))
  end

from tbl
```

Though if there's really a first-class boolean on every database, they would make bool_or/bit_or too, and it's shorter: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/679b2/6

```
select

  case when bool_or( num is null )  then 
    'OK' 
  else
    cast(max(num) as varchar(16))
  end

from tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `COUNT(column)` discounts null values, you could use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(num) THEN MAX(num) ELSE "OK" END
  FROM Test;
```

The DBMS I use (Informix) requires the types in the THEN and ELSE to be the same, so I ended up testing:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(num) THEN CAST(MAX(num) AS CHAR(10)) ELSE "OK" END
  FROM Test;
```

It is one of the verbose ways of casting (but it is Standard SQL); there are often shorthands available in a given DBMS.

Example output:

```
+ CREATE TABLE Test(Num INTEGER);
+ INSERT INTO Test VALUES(1);
+ INSERT INTO Test VALUES(2);
+ INSERT INTO Test VALUES(3);
+ INSERT INTO Test VALUES(NULL);
+ INSERT INTO Test VALUES(5);
+ INSERT INTO Test VALUES(6);
+ SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(num) THEN CAST(MAX(num) AS CHAR(10)) ELSE "OK" END
  FROM Test;
OK
+ DELETE FROM Test WHERE Num IS NULL;
+ SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(num) THEN CAST(MAX(num) AS CHAR(10)) ELSE "OK" END
  FROM Test;
6
```

Comment: +1 This would work but using SQL Server, you need to cast the `MAX(num)` to a `VARCHAR`. I have no idea how MySQL behaves on that.

Comment: @Lieven: Agreed; Informix required the cast too.  I was editing as you were commenting.

Answer (score 0):

In my sql

```
Select (Case When hasNull > 0 Then 'OK' Else mx End) As Result
From
(
  Select Max(num) as mx,Sum(Case When numIs Null Then 1 Else 0 End) as hasNull 
  From test 
) as t
```

Comment: I want OK if there is NULL in that column, 6 if there is no NULL in that column

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   select CASE num when num is null then "OK" else max(num) END from test;
```

Comment: What happened to the end of the case?

Comment: @KitHo, please try again as i have edited and let me know if still doesnt works as i didnt executed the query. will check it myself.

Comment: its working but also taking blank as null. lets have a try over it, if it is completing your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    case when ( select COUNT(*) from tableName where num is null ) > 0 then 'OK'
    else CONVERT(varchar, MAX(num) ) end as [num]
from tableName
```

Comment: Yes it'll always output `OK` as long as your `num` column is having a `NULL` value else it will provide `MAX` from that `num` column

Comment: That is not what I meant, this will **always** output `OK`, no matter what input's you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid running two queries (one to test for `NULL` values and then one to calculate `max` you can use `count(*)` and `count(num)` to count number of values with and without `NULL` values, like this (SQL Server syntax):

```
with TestQ as
(
   select max(num) as MaxNum, count(num) as NumCountNotNull, count(*) as NumCountTotal from nullAggTest
)
select 
   SpecialMax = case
      when NumCountNotNull < NumCountTotal then -1
      else MaxNum
   end
from TestQ
```

Note that I replaced your special value `OK` with `-1` for simplicity, otherwise you need to cast a little which is besides the point :-)